# Docker chef cookbook on windows

Tags: windows, docker, chef-infra, cookbook

I am using chef client to run cookbook with docker. It run on Ubuntu, but gives error on windows. Dependency of docker is already added in cookbook.

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker

I am using example of docker cookbook.

```
docker_image 'busybox' do
  action :pull
end


Error :
Recipe: tomcatcookbook::default
  * docker_image[busybox] action pull[2017-11-01T14:02:43+05:30] INFO: Processing docker_image[busybox] action pull (tomcatcookbook::default line 6)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `pull` on resource 'docker_image[busybox]'
    ================================================================================

    Excon::Error::Socket
    --------------------
    An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. - socket(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/tomcatcookbook/recipes/default.rb

      6: docker_image 'busybox' do
      7:   action :pull
      8: end
      9:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/tomcatcookbook/recipes/default.rb:6:in `from_file'

    docker_image("busybox") do
      action [:pull]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :docker_image
      cookbook_name "tomcatcookbook"
      recipe_name "default"
      repo "busybox"
      connection #<Docker::Connection:0x0000000005a288c0 @url="unix:///", @options={:socket=>"/var/run/docker.sock", :read_timeout=>120}>
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.5.3
    platform=windows
    platform_version=10.0.15063
    ruby=ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]
    program_name=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
    executable=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client

[2017-11-01T14:02:44+05:30] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation (the platform support list), Windows is not supported by that cookbook.

Comment: Yes, It is true but you can communicate through docker daemon through tcp port.  You can provide host as below and it will work in windows as well.
docker_image 'busybox' do
  action :pull
  host '127.0.0.1:2375'
end

If you can edit your answer, please.

Comment: "Not supported" doesn't mean "doesn't work". It means it is untested and should not be relied upon.